# selecting all fields from secondary table in eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, eloquent

Is there any reason why my query doesn't end?, I try to get all the values from the secondary table in a join in eloquent:

```
   Product::leftJoin('brands', 'products.brand_id', '=', 'brands.id')
                    ->leftJoin('product_categories', function($query) use ($parent){
                        $query->on('products.category_id', '=', 'product_categories.id')
                            ->where('product_categories.parent_id', $parent);
                    })
                    ->selectRaw('brands.*')
                    ->groupBy('brands.id') 
                    ->get();
```

If I select products.* the query goes fine, but with brands.* it never ends, Does someone knows what is happening?

If i run the sql directly in phpmyadmin, it gives me the result.

What i need with this query is to get all brands with existing products that its category has parent_id = $parent

Comment: I’d recommend using relationships in eloquent instead of SQL, so you’d have something like `Product::brands()->with('product_categories')` instead. [Read the docs on relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships).

Comment: Thanks for your answer Thomas, but what i need with this query is to get **all brands with existing products that its category has parent_id = $parent**, do you think i can do this with relationships?

Comment: You may want to read about the [Has Many Through](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through) relationship. It’ll take a few reads to get your head around it, but it sounds like it’ll do what you need to do. Also consider structuring your data around Eloquent, it’ll make your life much easier – and maybe the database more normalised.

Answer (score 0):

Well i don't know why eloquent has a problem with getting the fields from the second table, but I used query builder so this query work. I leave my "solution", maybe it is useful to someone:

```
    $brands = Product::leftJoin('brands', 'products.brand_id', '=', 'brands.id')
                    ->leftJoin('product_categories', function($query) use ($parent){
                        $query->on('products.category_id', '=', 'product_categories.id')
                            ->where('product_categories.parent_id', $parent);
                    })
                    ->selectRaw('brands.*')
                    ->groupBy('brands.id');
        $bindings = $brands->getBindings();
        $sql = $brands->toSql();
        $sql = vsprintf(str_replace('?', '%s', $sql), $bindings);
        $brands = \DB::select($sql);
```